# Breakpoint just breaking in one activity

Tags: java, android, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle

Ok, now I have tried all my ideas. I really hope someone has another one.

I have a android app in intellij, build using gradle.

I cant say what triggered it but suddenly most of my classes breakpoints wont fire . I have one activity where they work but breakpoints in all other classes is just skipped. This is only a problem on my device, not on an emulator.

Also in IntelliJ I the breakpoint are not mark in those classes are not marked with a checked symbol when I connect the debugger.

This is what I have tried so far:

- I have tried to throw an exception in the classes to know that they are being run
- I have removed and recompiled all class files and gradle derives
- I have created a new android project, transferring only gradle dependencies,  source and manifest

Any ideas, I am happy to try anything?

Gradle version 2.2, JDK 8

Comment: Will you confirm that the class containing breakpoint is called or not by adding logger in the code

Comment: I tested this by throwing an exception in the class

Comment: Turns out the debugging works in the emulator but not the phone. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled the USB debugging option in the phone?

Comment: Yes, and I am able to debug one class on the phone